# Align attribute not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, firefox

[This is my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3VSA/1/)

Here is the signup code, the code can be fully viewed in the jsfiddle

```
<li class="footer_row" align="center"><a href="" class="tsc_buttons2 grey" >sign up!</a></li>
```

All the Signup options is left aligned, in mozilla firefox , but it is perfect in the chrome browser in other few browsers, i just want to make it aligned centre in all the browsers, how can i make it ??

Comment: The `align` attribute has nothing to do with css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use position as absolute , and left alignment as 30 % , it is followed below,

```
.tsc_buttons2.grey { 
position: absolute;
left: 30%;
```

Answer (score 2):

Please give `text-align:center` in your `div.tsc_pricingtable03 li.footer_row class`.

```
div.tsc_pricingtable03 li.footer_row {
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 6px !important;
  padding-top: 14px !important;
  text-align: center /*changes here*/;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I did the position to absolute in the css

Answer (score 1):

you mixed the class name with attributes, should be:

```
<li class="footer_row align_center"><a href="" class="tsc_buttons2 grey" >sign up!</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
<li style="text-align:center" class="footer_row"><a class="tsc_buttons2 grey" href="">sign up!</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use style="text-align:center" inside the List Tag